# Multiple lines title cut in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using a cell array to display multiple lines title. It sometimes does not work well and do not understand why.  I am using `subplot` to define my axes;

Here is my code. The first two subplots work well but the third one title is cut, it only show the last two items ( C and D strings).

```
hf = figure;
subplot( 2, 2, 1 );
title({'test1', 'test2','test3', 'test4'});
subplot( 2, 2, 3 );
title({'testA', 'testB','testC', 'testD'});
subplot( 1, 2, 2 );
title({'A', 'B','C', 'D'});
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: This seems to be a MATLAB bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I can suggest you do the following:

```
sp3 = subplot(1,2,2);
title({'A', 'B','C', 'D'});
drawnow % force calculating the position *after* inserting the title
ph = sp3.Position; % get the desired position
sp3.delete % remove the axes
subplot( 2, 2, 1 );
title({'test1', 'test2','test3', 'test4'});
subplot( 2, 2, 3 );
title({'testA', 'testB','testC', 'testD'});
sp3 = subplot(1,2,2);
title({'A', 'B','C', 'D'});
sp3.Position = ph; % set the axes to the right hight
```

[image: subplot_title]

The idea is quite simple:

1. place the axes as you want them alone in the figure so they are resized correctly
2. Get their position values
3. Delete them  - so they won't interfere with the other axes
4. Place all the axes again
5. Set the position of all the clipped axes to their correct value.

The trick is using `drawnow`, so Matlab actually places all the parts of the axes before you get the position, otherwise, it goes wrong.

Comment: I have accepted the answer but by trying the code on MATLAB 2017a, the title is still cut on the right plot. It displays everything if I maximize the figure window.

Comment: @oro777 I fixed it now to work in all versions. I also understand now why it didn't work before.

Comment: I have tested on 2017a again and it works as expected, thank you.